# `Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--` when trying to use psvectorian with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, psvectorian

Using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian,fancyhdr,lipsum,multido}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\fancyhead[C]{\psvectorian[height=.7\baselineskip]{187}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\thepage}%
  \smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt]{\psvectorian[width=\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{85}}}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \psvectorian[width=.3\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{47}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
  \quad\multido{\i=102+1}{7}{\psvectorian[height=.8\baselineskip]{\i}\quad}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Operand stack:
   (/usr/share/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   run   run   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   run   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   run
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:793/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Permission denied
Current file position is 56
GPL Ghostscript 10.00.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
```

A PDF file gets produced, but is lacking the separators.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your example works for me with xelatex and lualatex (texlive 2022)

Comment: if you have xelatex-unsafe you could try that (it's needed for some pstricks features, but not this, I think)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have `xelatex-dev`, but thatz fails in the same way for the code above.

Comment: xelatex-dev is xelatex with the test release of latex so would be the same, xelatex-unsafe is xelatex configured so that xdvipdfmx calls ghostscript with some extensions used by pstricks enabled.